# How to have global database connection across the application in .net core with mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I am new to `.net core`. I have to build rest apis with `MongoDB`. I am wondering how can i have a global `database` connection and global configuration to get any collection of the database. What i found on the internet is that i can have `database name`, `connection string`, `collection name` in the `appsettings.json` and create a class like this

```
public class MongoDBSettings {
   public string ConnectionURI { get; set; } = null!;
   public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;
   public string CollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

After this i can configure this database connection in the `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.Configure<MongoDBSettings(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDB"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MongoDBService>();
```

Now for querying on the collection i should do like this in the respective service file let say `OrderService.cs`

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<Playlist> _playlistCollection;

public OrderService(IOptions<MongoDBSettings> mongoDBSettings) {
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionURI);
    IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
    _playlistCollection = database.GetCollection<Playlist>(mongoDBSettings.Value.CollectionName);
}

public async Task<List<Playlist>> GetAsync() { // my code here }
```

I understand all above mentioned approach. But the problem with this approach is that there is no global connection in the application. Every time i have to query on any collection then each entity service like `orderService.cs` will create a new database connection like i mentioned above like this

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionURI);
```

So this is inefficient. And second problem with this approach is that to get each database collection's instance i have to write these 3 lines of code in every `service.cs` file to get instance of each collection like this

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionURI);
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
_playlistCollection = database.GetCollection<Playlist>(mongoDBSettings.Value.CollectionName);
```

So how can i overcome both the issues and can i solve these 2 problems?

1. How to have global database connection that will be generic and can be used from every?
2. How to have generic logic to get instance of database collection's instance?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue before, and while MongoDB's .NET driver is efficient, I found using specialized tools like [dotConnect](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/) really streamlined my database connectivity. It usually provides a suite of ADO.NET providers that can enhance both performance and security.

You need to ensure MongoClient is registered as a singleton. This way, you're leveraging connection pooling efficiently.
Also, create a generic method in your service to fetch any collection. This will reduce redundancy and make your code cleaner.

If you need ODBC connections, [ODBC Driver](https://www.devart.com/odbc/) is a lifesaver. It's been very efficient in my projects, ensuring very secure database interactions.

With these tools you'll find managing database connections in .NET Core much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [dbcontext class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) that will store all of your tables (dbsets) so you can access them anywhere on the application. I'll use [this repo](https://github.com/rmed1na/Bucker/tree/master/Bucker) as a basic example.

You have the [context class and it's interface](https://github.com/rmed1na/Bucker/tree/master/Bucker/Data/Context) which are later on injected via DI on to every controller or class constructor you need. (Check [line 75 on Startup.cs](https://github.com/rmed1na/Bucker/blob/master/Bucker/Startup.cs)).

Once that is done you might use your context interface anywhere. For example, in a [repository class](https://github.com/rmed1na/Bucker/blob/master/Bucker/Data/Repositories/UserRepository.cs). As for your db configuration settings I don't see why you might need to have that all over the application. Maybe you only needed at Startup.cs but in case you do check out [the options monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsmonitor-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) object. It comes handy when you need configurations from appSettings.json into your objects anywhere on the application. Just make sure you're not exposing any app secrets publicly.